# URL Rewriting with .HTACCESS not working in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My URL looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/website/comments.php?topic_id=16
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/website/comments/my-news-article/16.php
```

I have applied this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.php$ comments.php?id=$2
```

I have also turned on `Rewrite_module` in Apache.

But it's not working.

Comment: where does `my-news-article` come from? Is it part of the original URL?

Comment: not correctly specified there are parts that where needed to solve the problem you wanna rewrite two parameters but you are GET-ing only one in the url

Answer (score 1):

Always consider the entire URL path.  Yours includes /website, so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /website
RewriteRule ^comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.php$ comments.php?id=$2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the changes, but still not achieving the result i want.

Comment: First make sure the path to `comments.php` is correct. If that's not the problem turn on rewrite logging and check the results.  Do you have any other errors?

Answer (score 0):

RewriteBase is used for per-directory directives. Try

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/website/comments/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\.php$ /website/comments.php?topic_id=$2
```

Works for me. Note that I also changed the query string parameter at the end of the line to "topic_id". Maybe this is another cause of error. If it still fails, check that the configuration is in the right virtual host config.